# Javascript AJAX insert value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I am making a site that shows the value of a .TXT file, this is what I got so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#responsecontainer").load("info.txt");

var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  $("#responsecontainer").load('info.txt');
 }, 1000);
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

So it get's the string from info.txt and puts it inside the div resonsecontainer.

But now I want that same string to be in a value of a meter, and also a auto updater for that. The code is:

```
<meter id="cpumeter" value="60" min="0" max="120.47" title="GB">
<div class="meter-gauge">
<span style="width: 46.42%;"></span>
</div>
</meter>
```

How do I autoupdate the value="60" to the string of the info.txt?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking - are you trying to change the `span ` width? Or change the .TXT file? Or? What is the "meter"? Do you mean a progress bar?

Comment: I am trying to put the string of info.txt in the value="here" from meter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a callback argument to `.load()`, and it will receive the contents of the file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loadInfo() {
        $("#responsecontainer").load('info.txt', function(info) {
            $("#cpumeter").val(parseFloat(info));
        });
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    loadInfo();
    var refreshId = setInterval(loadInfo, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Hi Barmer! Thanks for helping me. But when I used this code it is no longer auto updating and also the cpumeter isn't doing anything?

Comment: Sorry for the command before this, yes there are 2 errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: loadinfo is not defined
jquery-latest.js:8196 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLMeterElement': The provided double value is non-finite.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, `loadinfo` should have been `loadInfo` in the `setInterval`

Comment: I've added a call to `parseFloat` in case there's extra whitespace in the file.

Comment: It worked after updating the loadInfo and parseFloat! Thanks for helping!

Comment: For some reason it didn't, probably because the txt file contains '30%'

Comment: Well, the way you wrote the question implied that the contents of the file would be a proper value for the `value=` attribute.

Comment: If the file contains a percentage, it's probably not the right thing to put in `value=""`, because the range of your meter is `0` to `120.47`, not `0` to `100`.

Comment: You probably need to do `.val(parseFloat(info)/100 * 120.47)`

Comment: Thanks for that tip Barmer! I might ever need that, but I just changed the max to 100 so I dont need that :)